# How we use NGSplitMenuController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

I want to use `NGSplitMenuController` in our *Swift* program. How to use it?

I want to make a menu as follows:

[image]

Comment: can yo u show ur tried code or else what the probelm faced or where u struck

Comment: this library are given at    https://github.com/nitingeorge227/NGSplitMenuController     they written code in objective c  how we use it in our swift program

Comment: @RamMani Are you familiar with the concept of Bridging?

Comment: @RamMani Then read [Apple's documentation on using Bridging headers for using swift and Objective C simultaneously in a project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)